# Sign in error with HTML and Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase and html. The problem is sign in process allowed all email to sign in. I have activated firebase authentication email/password.

Below I attached the code. please do help me with posting the right code.

---

(HTML Coding)

[HTML CODING Notes: i have enter the firebase code and activate the firebase]

(Picture)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqgfj.png)

---

[Here is the javascript. i already try to follow the guidelines from the firebase but did not work. Below are the code i did try

```
var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}
```

(Picture of current coding)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqgfj.png)

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Add the code here

Comment: Always edit the content in your question not as separate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(data => {
// Successfully sign in
// ...
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

For more info, you can visit:- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth